# Download Maven artifacts in Jenkins from another repo if one fails

Tags: maven, repository, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins build I have a settings.xml file for pulling Maven dependencies. An artifact, if not found, should be downloaded from another Maven repo not specified in a settings file. Can this be done using code in Jenkinsfile? Any thought will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not add all relevant repositories to the `settings.xml`?

Comment: Due to certain setup constraint we cannot change the default `settings.xml`.

Comment: You can define an additional `settings.xml` and give it as parameter to Maven.